# How to tell PowerShell script to continue after CTRL+C

Tags: windows, docker, powershell

I have a ps1 script that tells my project to build and execute result in Docker.
And when I need to stop whats running in Docker - I hit Ctrl+C.
After I hit Ctrl+C, Docker containers gracefully stopped and that is it. Next ps1 commands are not being run at all.

Here is the example of my script:

```
git pull
mvn clean install
cd .\target
docker-compose up --build
docker-compose down
docker system prune -f --volumes
cd D:\
```

So it does not execute any commands after `docker-compose up --build` because I hit Ctrl+C.
Is there any other way to stop docker process? Or a way to tell that my commands still needs to be executed after Ctrl+C?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest for you would be to split the script in two PowerShell scripts.

1. The terminatable tasks that you need to perform before hitting Ctrl + C
2. Rest of the script to continue

Suppose you have the following script **Part1.ps1**, to represent your pre Ctrl + C tasks, (located as **C:\Part1.ps1**)

```
For ($i = 1; $i -lt 100; $i++)
{
    Write-Host "$i. First Part of Script. Replace with your code."
    Sleep 1
}
```

Now you can call the above in a second script or at PowerShell command-line, as following

```
# Put & call Pre CTRL + C tasks in in a separate script file (C:\Part1.ps1)

$proc = Start-Process "powershell.exe" -ArgumentList "-file C:\Part1.ps1" -Wait

    
#Continue below if The above part was terminated by Ctrl + C (or completed)

Write-Host "We're here now after the first script is terminated or ended."
```

Comment: Your suggestion is launching first part of the script in a separate window. I really wouldn't want that, unfortunately. But thanks!

Comment: @Leviann yes that is expected. Try `-NoNewWindow` flag to see if that works for you.

Comment: Tried it, yes. But it works even worse when I hit Ctrl+C. It stops containers and waits for some kind of input. Any input will just kill the process and nothing else will be executed